# retrieve date and droplist data from database using php

Tags: php

I am having problem when I want to retrieve data from my database. I had a table name "module" and contain some column name "moduleCode" , "msa", "ese", "mue"

columns "msa", "ese", "mue" is date format

when I retrieve data from my database and want to display exactly same data in the webpage, my webpage did not display at all. 
Can somebody help, I am not sure where I went wrong.

Below is a picture I want it to look like [Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQM0E.png)

This is my code:

```
 <?php
    include "dbFunctions.php";

$theID = $_POST['examID'];

//echo $theID;

$query = "SELECT * FROM module
WHERE moduleCode = '$theID'";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die(mysqli_error($link));
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Edit Exam Schedule</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php if ($row != null){?>
        <form method="POST" action="doEditExamSchedule.php">
        <div style="width:350px;">



     <label for="id_module_code">Module: </label></td>
            <td><select id="id_module_code" name="module_code">
            <?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {?>
            <option value="<?php echo $row['moduleCode'];?>"><?php echo $row['moduleCode'];?></option>



            <?php } ?>
      </select>
         <br/><br/> 

        MSA: <input type="date" name="msa" value>
                <?php echo date($row['msa']); ?>
        <br/><br/>  

        ESE: <input type="date" name="ese">
                <?php echo $row['ese']; ?>
        <br/><br/>

        MUE: <input type="date" name="mue">
                <?php echo $row['mue']; ?>
        <br/><br/>


    </div>
        <input type="hidden" name="i_id" value="<?php echo $theID?>"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="i_module" value="<?php echo $row['moduleCode']?>"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="i_msa" value="<?php echo $row['msa']?>"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="i_ese" value="<?php echo $row['ese']?>"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="i_mue" value="<?php echo $row['mue']?>"/>

        <input type="submit" name="i_submit" value="Update"/>
    </form>
    <?php } ?>


</body>
```

Comment: can you post the error

Comment: i am not sure where i got wrong, i just cannot display the data in the webpage, i had upload a picture on it, can you help me take a look

Comment: $row["msa"] did you try using ""

Comment: yes. did not work at all

Comment: add files to dropbox

Comment: connection files and required files

Comment: Are you actually making the connection to the database? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: you sure that your array is not empty

Comment: Yes. include "dbFunctions.php"; is the file contain the database connection

Comment: Remove the `while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))` as you are already doing `$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);` above, so when you do a 2nd fetch it tries to find a 2nd returned row. Since you are probably only returning 1 row from that query, then there is nothing to show for a 2nd row.

Comment: Thank a lot, you have solve my problem @Sean

Comment: Also, your `MSA`, `ESE`, and `MUE` `<input>`s don't have the `value`s inside the tag properly - `<input type="date" name="msa" value><?php echo date($row['msa']); ?>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
MSA: <input type="date" name="msa" value="<?php echo date($row['msa']); ?>">
<br/><br/>  

ESE: <input type="date" name="ese" value="<?php echo $row['ese']; ?>">
<br/><br/>

MUE: <input type="date" name="mue" value="<?php echo $row['mue']; ?>">
<br/><br/>
```